# The module has not been deployed. BUILD FAILED

Tags: netbeans

```
C:\Users\Danger\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LoginServer\nbproject\build-impl.xml:683: The module has     not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED
```

I have made a basic login Servlet Project in netbeans 6.9.
Clean and build Done..
When I'm executing the project it throws the above error.
What to Do?

Reffered some previous Questions and answers I'm not satisfied with the answers.
I deployed the project too it still says build failed

Comment: What kind of project is that (JavaSE, Web, some other?) Is the Tomcat (or any other Servlet container into which you deploy) running? Is there anything in the Tomcat logfile? Is there anything in the NetBeans logfile? "View -> IDE Log") and finally: Why are you using such an outdated NetBeans version?

Comment: Its an Java Web Project(Web Application). Yes the tomcat is running fine. this is my IDE Log....  In-place deployment at C:\Users\Danger\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LoginServer\build\web
C:\Users\Danger\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LoginServer\build\web\META-INF\context.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
C:\Users\Danger\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LoginServer\nbproject\build-impl.xml:720: The module has not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds) and earlier i used to use netbeans 7.1 there was an deployment error to so i tried to switch to an older version...

Comment: Don't post logfiles in comments. Edit your question.

Comment: Its an Java Web Project(Web Application). Yes the tomcat is running fine. The problem is i cannot deploy the ide log says there is an erron in build-impl.xml at line 720 could not locate the error.